# BreakPoints with gridlisttiles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Is it possible to put sm={12} lg={6} on Grid List Tile components so that they take up the whole screen on small screens but only half the screen on large screens? If not is there anyway to make the grid list restructure so there are less grid list tiles per row on smaller screens? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use Material UI's [breakpoints](https://material-ui.com/layout/breakpoints/) to detect the device dimensions. There is a higher order component `withWidth` that you can use to make the prop `width` available in your component.

Now, in your component, you can then change the `cols` property of the `GridList` based on your requirements.

Something like

```
<GridList className={classes.gridList} cols={this.props.width === 'sm' ? 12 : 6}>
```

Note: Grid lists by default take up full width of the parent container.